# Pandas Groupby with Group Concat for integer values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

My pandas dataframe looks like this, I am looking to group it by keys and concatenate the id's comma separated and create a new dataframe. Now the issue here is id column is integer.

```
df:
          key      id
    0   abc     5073138
    1   abcd    5025923
    2   abc     7453197
    3   abcd    5032121
    4   abcd    5032121
    5   abc     5032121


new df:

         key       id
     0  abc     5073138,7453197,5032121
     1  abcd    5025923,5096021,5032121
```

I tried using group by with apply and aggregate but didn't work

```
df.groupby('key').apply(lambda x: ','.join(x.id))

df.groupby('key').agg({'id' : lambda x: ', '.join(str(x))})
```

Answer (score 5):

Your first solution almost worked:

```
df.groupby('key').id.apply(lambda x: ','.join(map(str, x)))
```

If the id column is converted to str in advance, it's simpler:

```
df.id = df.id.astype(str)
df.groupby('key').id.apply(','.join)
```

Though personally I dislike apply, and you may get better performance without it:

```
df.id = df.id.astype(str)
df.id += ',' # add trailing commas
df.groupby('key').id.sum().str[:-1] # sum of strs is concatenation
```

This gives the same result but in a fully vectorized way.

Comment: Another alternative with `str.cat`... `df.groupby('key').id.apply(lambda x: x.str.cat(sep=',')).reset_index()`